# Persistent CSRF Token Rejection in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I'm using Devise for authentication in a Rails 4.2 app. Most of the users are not having any issues logging in and getting their work done, but there is one user in particular that appears to consistently have a bad CSRF token and can't log in.

Of course, the following is what's logged:

```
W, [2015-02-17T20:58:19.261194 #1936]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
I, [2015-02-17T20:58:19.263556 #1936]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 5ms
F, [2015-02-17T20:58:19.276795 #1936] FATAL -- :
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
<stack trace>
```

Perusing the logs shows me that the user's CSRF token changes as you'd expect, but it is consistently (100% of the time) rejected by the server.

Originally, I thought this was an issue with that user's browser. I started logging the user agent when logins are attempted and asked that user to try with several browsers; she has, and all are able to reproduce the same issue.
I reset her password and was able to log into the account using new credentials. She still cannot log in.

She has dumped her cache and cleared cookies several times. Likewise, a runthrough with anti-malware software returns no results (this is probably the most suspect).

What am I missing? Is there something I need to do on the server side in order to fix this issue, or is it likely an issue with her computer itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, at least temporarily. After some searching through issues on the Devise issue tracker, I happened across this snippet (for placement in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`) that seemed to help:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_rails_session_#{Rails.env}", domain: :all
```

The user is not having any problems signing in at this point. I suspect it was either that the user was not properly clearing her cookies or that there was a mixup somewhere in the code. At any rate, it seems to be fixed.